# Help! My Marigold is Dying

Tags: houseplants

I got this marigold plant a two months ago. Due to circumstances the plant has suffered a whole week of  dehydration as the person in charge of her didn't water her at all. This is a picture of the plant now

I know nothing about plants since this is my first one ever, and I want to know what we can do to save it and help it get healthy again besides watering it. Any advice is helpful. Thank you! [image]

Comment: Welcome Aleisha! I've grown marigolds for years. Frequently they've dried out until they look as sad as yours. I want to reassure you that this plant is alive and not a lost cause at all. Do what Bamboo recommended. I would also add more potting soil to the whole pot. It adds nutrients and holds water. Make it level and high enough to cover the brown section at the base and support the structure.  If you have roots showing, cover them. It may take a few weeks but you'll be ecstatic when this comes back and gives you a long flowering season!

Comment: Another important thing with marigolds is the material of the pot. Yours looks like plastic, which is best. I've learned the hard way that clay or ceramic pots dry out so quickly that the marigold suffers.

Answer (score 1):

This is Tagetes patula, common name French marigold. There is nothing you can do other than cut it back by half and keep it watered - not soaking wet or sitting in water, but keep  it watered when the soil feels just about dry to the touch. These are actually frost sensitive annuals which are usually planted outdoors in summer, when the temperatures are warm enough, and that's where yours should be if your temperatures are high enough. They like sun, but while its in this state, to give it some chance of recovery, don't stand it in sun unless/until it's grown again. The presence of the flower (which hasn't shrivelled and dropped off) means its not yet dead, but best to cut that off too at this point - it needs to concentrate on producing new leaves instead.